# Вывести данные только когда все данные в столбце равны определенному значению

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g

подскажите как лучше организовать такой запрос.

Первая таблица с номерами заказов.
Вторая таблица с товарами по этим заказам.
Использую соединение по номеру заказа.

```
select * from orders
  join items on orders.order = items.order
```

Но беда в том что мне необходимо выводить заказы только те в которых для примера items = 'яблоко'.
Например такой заказ я должен пропустить:

```
 order    item
заказ1   яблоко
заказ1   яблоко
заказ1   апельсин
```

А этот вывести в запросе

```
 order    item
заказ2   яблоко
заказ2   яблоко
заказ2   яблоко
```

Если делаю какой либо фильтр то фильтр отрезает фильтруемую позицию но выводит весь остальной заказ, что не корректно для моей задачи.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте что-то такое:

```sql
select order from orders
group by order
having count(dictinct item) = 1
```

Так вы определите номера заказов, в которых один вид `item`. Дальше можно сделать `join` обратно с `orders` и вывести все такие заказы целиком.